# How to apply SharpMap.VectorStyle theme on VectorLayer if DataSource is FeatureDataTable?

Tags: c#, gis, sharpmap

I tried Vector Layer theme when I used ShapeFile as data source for vector layer. But when I am trying to achieve same thing with custom polygon data it is not working.

Below is the code I used:

```cs
Dictionary<string, SharpMap.Styles.IStyle> styles = new Dictionary<string, SharpMap.Styles.IStyle>();
                styles.Clear();
                styles.Add("NONE", m_noneStyleDefault);
                foreach (ListViewItem tn in _arlv)
                {
                    DataRow _row = (DataRow)tn.Tag;
                    r = labelData.NewRow();
                    var wkbreader = new NetTopologySuite.IO.WKTReader();
                    var geom = wkbreader.Read(_row["ogr_geometry"].ToString());
                    r["FID"] = (Int32)_row["ogr_fid"];
                    r["NAME"] = _row["sovereignt"].ToString();
                    r["SOV_A3"] = _row["sov_a3"].ToString().Trim().ToUpper();
                    r["TYPE"] = _row["mytype"].ToString();
                    r.Geometry = geom;

                    labelData.Rows.Add(r);
                    styles.Add(_row["sov_a3"].ToString().Trim().ToUpper(), m_selectStyleDefault);
                }

                m_vlCountries.DataSource = new SharpMap.Data.Providers.GeometryProvider(labelData);
                //m_vlCountries.Style = m_selectStyleDefault;

                m_vlCountries.Theme = new SharpMap.Rendering.Thematics.UniqueValuesTheme<string>("SOV_A3", styles, m_noneStyleDefault);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `SharpMap.Data.Providers.GeometryFeatureProvider` instead of plain `GeometryProvider`